# Autolayout changes the child view size

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

1. I have an view in my view controller say HeaderView.
2. I set the height for HeaderView using the auto layout to 85.
3. I have given other constraints like leading and trailing space for this view with respect to the super view.
4. Everything looks fine in the x code preview and there are no errors in the x code.
5. When I run the application in iPhone6 the size of HeaderView changes to almost 200.

Does anyone encountered this before?
Whats going wrong in the auto layout?

Edit:
[image: Layout contraints]

Comment: How did you set the height? As AutoLayout will honour your height constraints if it doesn't conflict with others.

Comment: I added the height constraint directly using the pin option.
Also X code does not warn any conflicts.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your view's constraint?

Comment: The iPhone 6 resolution is 750x1334.
The same resolution image I get when i take screenshot. But the height of the view is not 85. Its around 200.

Comment: it looks alright to me. I don't know, what could be wrong?

Comment: One thing i noticed is that in the "resolve auto layout issues" button the menu for "Reset to suggested constraints" was enabled.
When I clicked that it removed height and width constraints and replaced it with Horizontal and vertical space. ( basically trailing and bottom constraints are added to the view. )